# I need to study space, planets and black holes, how do I study them on my own

Tags: black-hole, galaxy, gravity, cosmology, general-relativity

I need to study space, planets and black holes, how do I study them on my own, knowing that I am an Arab and I do not know English. I use translation applications. I speak with you. Can you help me with a site or YouTube channel? I don’t want books

Comment: Have you tried searching?   https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D8%AB%D9%82%D8%A8+%D8%A3%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AF

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific.  Are you just curious about astronomy?  Is this for a class you are taking?  Are you asking how to be an astronomer?  My advise in most of these cases would be to pick up an introductory book on astronomy in your native language and start reading, as much as you say you don't want books.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about astronomy itself, but rather is asking how to access study resources in another language, which could apply to *any* area of study.

Comment: USE SUBTITLES. on YouTube(The cog symbol bottom right l), search in english: planets science, solar system, black holes, astronomical object types, star types, quasars, and  SUBTITLES translate to arabic will work sometimes in the cog button lower right. Good luck.

Comment: You may have setbacks in your studies, but keep looking up.

Comment: There is a [Dubai Astronomy Group](https://twitter.com/dubaiastronomy?s=09) you could get in touch with. They can possibly help with basic Astronomy and resources in Arabic. Also, an [askreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/) question might help you reach a wider audience who could help you out.

Answer (score 4):

1. I am sorry to say, but the best resources are still books. If it is really a no-go, read further. It is very likely, that you can find and buy astronomy books on Arabic on the Internet. First start with popular science books. Buy multiple books. To learn something, books are still somehow far better than the Internet.
2. Check the Arabic wikipedia, like [this article](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%85_%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%81).
3. Just think freely. Imagine a question, *anything*, like *"How far are we from the edge of Universe?"*<sup>1</sup>. My experiences is that the resources on my first language (far lesser amount of speakers than Arabic) are significantly lesser, but they exist. Enter the question on Arabic into the google search.
4. Any time if something is not clear, come here and ask.

<sup>1</sup><sub>It is actually a bad question, but you don't know yet, why. [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/32426) is the answer, why. This was only an example question.</sub>